# How to read gz file line by line in Raku

Tags: raku

I'm trying to read a huge gz file line by line in Raku.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
my $file = 'huge_file.gz';
for $file.IO.lines -> $line {
    say $line;
}
```

But this give error that I have a malformed UTF-8.  I can't see how to get this to read gzipped material from the help page https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode#UTF8-C8 or https://docs.raku.org/language/io

I want to accomplish the same thing as was done in Perl5: http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-read-and-write-compressed-files-in-perl

How can I read a gz file line by line in Raku?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are after a quick solution you can read the lines from the stdout pipe of a gzip process:

```
my $proc = run :out, "gzip", "--to-stdout", "--decompress", "MyFile.gz"

for $proc.out.lines -> $line {
    say $line;
}

$proc.out.close;
```

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend using the module `Compress::Zlib` for this purpose. You can find the [readme and code on github](https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-Compress-Zlib/) and install it with `zef install Compress::Zlib`.

This example is taken from the test file number 3 titled "wrap":

```
use Test;
use Compress::Zlib;

gzspurt("t/compressed.gz", "this\nis\na\ntest");

my $wrap = zwrap(open("t/compressed.gz"), :gzip);
is $wrap.get, "this\n", 'first line roundtrips';
is $wrap.get, "is\n", 'second line roundtrips';
is $wrap.get, "a\n", 'third line roundtrips';
is $wrap.get, "test", 'fourth line roundtrips';
```

This is probably the easiest way to get what you want.

Comment: I'm can't use `zef`, which I think is Perl6's version of cpanm `con@con-VirtualBox:~/Scripts/perl6/zef$ bin/zef 
===SORRY!===
Could not find Zef::CLI at line 3 in:
    /home/con/.perl6
    /usr/lib/perl6/site
    /usr/lib/perl6/vendor
    /usr/lib/perl6
    CompUnit::Repository::AbsolutePath<94490554980752>
    CompUnit::Repository::NQP<94490534027648>
    CompUnit::Repository::Perl5<94490534027688>
con@con-VirtualBox:~/Scripts/perl6/zef$ /home/con/Scripts/perl6/rakudo-star-2018.10/install/share/perl6/site/bin/zef===SORRY!===
No candidate found for 'zef' that match your criteria `

Comment: @con your environment is not setup properly. In the first command we see its looking for a `perl6` installed with visibility to `/usr/lib/perl6/site`, but the second command you are invoking a zef installed under `/home/con/Scripts/perl6/rakudo-star-2018.10/install/share/perl6/site` -- that is a different `perl6` installation than what `perl6` command is invoking. The proper way to invoke an uninstalled copy of zef would have looked like `con@con-VirtualBox:~/Scripts/perl6/zef$ perl6 -I. bin/zef`

Answer (score 7):

use the  `read-file-content` method in the [Archive::Libarchive](https://github.com/frithnanth/perl6-Archive-Libarchive/tree/master/examples) module, but i don't know if the method read all lines into memory at once:

```
use Archive::Libarchive; 
use Archive::Libarchive::Constants;

my $a = Archive::Libarchive.new: operation => LibarchiveRead, file => 'test.tar.gz';
my Archive::Libarchive::Entry $e .= new;

my $log = '';
while $a.next-header($e) {
    $log = get-log($a,$e) if $e.pathname.ends-with('.txt');
}

sub get-log($a, $e) {
    return $a.read-file-content($e).decode('UTF8-C8');
}
```