# Perl6: large gzipped files read line by line

Tags: gzip, raku

I'm trying to read a gz file line by line in Perl6, however, I'm getting blocked:

1. [How to read gz file line by line in Perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010992/how-to-read-gz-file-line-by-line-in-perl6) however, this method, reading everything into `:out` uses far too much RAM to be usable except on very small files.
2. I don't understand how to use Perl6's `Compress::Zlib` to get everything line by line, although I opened an issue on their github https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-Compress-Zlib/issues/17
3. I'm trying Perl5's `Compress::Zlib` to translate this code, which works perfectly in Perl5:

> ```
> use Compress::Zlib;
> my $file = "data.txt.gz";
> my $gz = gzopen($file, "rb") or die "Error reading $file: $gzerrno";
>
> while ($gz->gzreadline($_) > 0) {
>     # Process the line read in $_
> }
>
> die "Error reading $file: $gzerrno" if $gzerrno != Z_STREAM_END ;
> $gz->gzclose() ;
> ```

to something like this using `Inline::Perl5` in Perl6:

```
use Compress::Zlib:from<Perl5>;
my $file = 'chrMT.1.vcf.gz';
my $gz = Compress::Zlib::new(gzopen($file, 'r');
while ($gz.gzreadline($_) > 0) {
  print $_;
}
$gz.gzclose();
```

but I can't see how to translate this :(

4. I'm confused by Lib::Archive example https://github.com/frithnanth/perl6-Archive-Libarchive/blob/master/examples/readfile.p6 I don't see how I can get something like item 3 here
5. There should be something like

`for $file.IO.lines(gz) -> $line {` or something like that in Perl6, if it exists, I can't find it.

How can I read a large file line by line without reading everything into RAM in Perl6?

Comment: Re: *" using Inline::Perl5"*:  For the call to `$gz.gzreadline($_)`: it seems `gzreadline` tries to return the line read from the zip file by modifying its input argument `$_` (treated as an output argument, but not a true Perl 5 reference variable), but the value is not returned to the Perl 6 script.

Comment: Some more on the Perl 5 `gzreadline` function: In Perl 5 you can modify an input argument that is not a reference, and the change will be  reflected in the caller. This is done by modifying entries in the special `@_` array variable. For example: `sub quote { $_[0] = "'$_[0]'" } $str = "Hello"; quote($str)` will quote `$str` even if `$str` is not passed by reference. I am not sure if `Inline::Perl5` can handle these kind of output arguments

Comment: Regarding item #4, just to clarify: the underlying library provides an `archive_read_data_block()` which is generic and has to work for every kind of file in every archive format. The `read-file-content` method returns the whole file in a `Buf`. To read a file line by line one should write one's own method using `Archive::Libarchive::Raw`, but I see that there are simpler ways to do it, as shown in the answers to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update** Now tested, which revealed an error, now fixed.

## Solution #2

```
use Compress::Zlib;

my $file   = "data.txt.gz" ;
my $handle = try open $file or die "Error reading $file: $!" ;
my $zwrap  = zwrap($handle, :gzip) ;

for $zwrap.lines {
    .print
}

CATCH { default { die "Error reading $file: $_" } }

$handle.close ;
```

I've tested this with a small gzipped text file.

I don't know much about gzip etc. but figured this out based on:

- Knowing P6;
- Reading [`Compress::Zlib`'s `README`](https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-Compress-Zlib/blob/master/README.md) and choosing the `zwrap` routine;
- Looking at the module's source code, in particular the signature of [the `zwrap` routine](https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-Compress-Zlib/blob/master/lib/Compress/Zlib.pm6#L409) `our sub zwrap ($thing, :$zlib, :$deflate, :$gzip)`;
- And trial and error, mainly to guess that I needed to pass the `:gzip` adverb.

---

Please comment on whether my code works for you. I'm guessing the main thing is whether it's fast enough for the large files you have.

## A failed attempt at solution #5

With solution #2 working I would have expected to be able to write just:

```
use Compress::Zlib ;
.print for "data.txt.gz".&zwrap(:gzip).lines ;
```

But that fails with:

```
No such method 'eof' for invocant of type 'IO::Path'
```

This is presumably because this module was written before the reorganization of the `IO` classes.

That led me to [@MattOates' *`IO::Handle` like object with `.lines` ?*  issue](https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-Compress-Zlib/issues/15). I note no response and I saw no related repo at https://github.com/MattOates?tab=repositories.

Answer (score 5):

I am focusing on the [`Inline::Perl5`](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5) solution that you tried.

For the call to `$gz.gzreadline($_)`: it seems like [`gzreadline`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Compress::Zlib) tries to return the line read from the zip file [by modifying its input argument `$_`](https://metacpan.org/source/PMQS/IO-Compress-2.084/lib/Compress/Zlib.pm#L188) (treated as an output argument, but it is not a true Perl 5 reference variable<sup>[1]</sup>), but the modified value is not returned to the Perl 6 script.

Here is a possoble workaround: 
Create a wrapper module in the curent directory, e.g. **./MyZlibWrapper.pm**:

```
package MyZlibWrapper;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Compress::Zlib ();
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT = qw(gzopen);
our $VERSION = 0.01;

sub gzopen {
    my ( $fn, $mode ) = @_;
    my $gz = Compress::Zlib::gzopen( $fn, $mode );
    my $self = {gz => $gz}; 
    return bless $self, __PACKAGE__;
}

sub gzreadline {
    my ( $self ) = @_;
    my $line = "";
    my $res = $self->{gz}->gzreadline($line);
    return [$res, $line];
}

sub gzclose {
    my ( $self ) = @_;
    $self->{gz}->gzclose();
}    

1;
```

Then use `Inline::Perl5` on this wrapper module instead of `Compress::Zlib`. For example **./p.p6**:

```
use v6;
use lib:from<Perl5> '.';
use MyZlibWrapper:from<Perl5>;
my $file = 'data.txt.gz';
my $mode = 'rb';
my $gz = gzopen($file, $mode);
loop {
    my ($res, $line) = $gz.gzreadline();
    last if $res == 0;
    print $line;
}
$gz.gzclose();
```

<sub>[1] 
 In Perl 5 you can modify an input argument that is not a reference, and the change will be reflected in the caller. This is done by modifying entries in the special `@_` array variable. For example: `sub quote { $_[0] = "'$_[0]'" } $str = "Hello"; quote($str)` will quote `$str` even if `$str` is not passed by reference.</sub>

Comment: You can `use lib:from<Perl5> '.';` to change the paths that Perl5 uses. Then `use MyZlibWrapper:from<Perl5>;` will work.